# Yii2 AccessControl and RBAC Update Own Record

Tags: php, yii2

After following [this guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html) I am unable to get the "update own record" type of functionality to work.  Here is what I have.

Admin and Author roles. Author has the `imageUpdateOwn` permission which has the `imageUpdate` permission as a child. The `imageUpdateOwn` permission has the `isOwner` rule assigned to it. All other pertinent/related code is below.

**Database**

[image: database]

**OwnerRule.php**

The `Image` model has a `created_by` property which is the owner of the record.

```
public function execute($user, $item, $params)
{
    return isset($params['model']) ? $params['model']->created_by == $user : false;
}
```

**ImageController.php AccessControl**

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['update'],
                    'roles' => ['imageUpdate'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['delete'],
                    'roles' => ['imageDelete'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['index', 'view', 'create'],
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => false,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

**ImageController.php action**

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if (\Yii::$app->user->can('imageUpdate', ['model' => $model])) {
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    } else {
        throw new HttpException(403, 'You do not have permission to update this record.');
    }
}
```

In my testing, I logged in as the author and uploaded image 1000 then logged in as the admin and uploaded image 1001. Performing the following quick test while logged in as each user yields the expected results.

```
$image1000 = \app\models\Image::findOne(1000); // author uploaded
$image1001 = \app\models\Image::findOne(1001); // admin uploaded

echo \Yii::$app->user->can('imageUpdate', ['model' => $image1000]) . "<br>";
echo \Yii::$app->user->can('imageUpdate', ['model' => $image1001]);
```

When logged in as admin, I get "true" for each of the echo statements. When logged in as the author, I get "true" only for image 1000. This tells me the authorization is returning the correct permissions as expected with the isOwner rule I created.

However, when I try to actually go to the update action, I can't even get past the access control.  Instead of getting the 403 error that I specified in the action (which is what I expect) I get the generic "You are not allowed to perform this action" error. This seems to be because I have the default access set to deny. If I set the default access to allow, I can get through to the action and I get the expected 403 error message. That tells me the action isn't allowing me through.

I am not sure if the `imageUpdateOwn` role should be listed in the access control but having it there does not change the results (presumably because `imageUpdate` is a child of `imageUpdateOwn` so by having the latter, the author will also have the former).

What am I missing in the above that is completely preventing me from accessing the update action when logged in as the author?

**Edit 1**

Perhaps because the model isn't loaded at the time the access control is being checked, the created_by user can't be evaluated. If that is the case, I'm confused since the author has `imageUpdate` by way of `imageUpdateOwn` it should be allowing the access to continue. Unless they only get `imageUpdate` when the rule associated with `imageUpdateOwn` passes.  In which case the author would never "get" the access associated with the `imageUpdate` role until the model can be evaluated. Meaning I would have to allow all authenticated users to access the `update` action and only check for the permission inside the action itself, once the model is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

From further testing and more research, here is what I have found (which hopefully someone can confirm).

The admin role is directly assigned `imageUpdate` and is able to update any image. The author is directly assigned `imageUpdateOwn` which has `imageUpdate` as a child.  Though `imageUpdate` is a child of an assigned permission, it will not be given if a rule on the parent prevents the parent from being given. Basically, if `imageUpdateOwn` evaluates to false (meaning the author user is not the owner of a given image), then the author will not be given the child permission of `imageUpdate` either.

The reason the author role does not get past the access control for any record is because at the time access control is evaluated, the model is not available. If the model is not available, the rule attached to `imageUpdateOwn` will evaluate as false (if you don't have the record you can't check its owner), which means its child `imageUpdate` permission will not be given either.

The resolution is to allow all authenticated users through the access control and then check for the specific permission in the action itself such as the following:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
...
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if (\Yii::$app->user->can('imageUpdate', ['model' => $model])) {
        // Save the record and redirect the user
    } else {
        throw new HttpException(403, 'You do not have permission to update this record.');
    }
}
```

This ensures that non-authenticated users are not allowed anywhere near the action while authenticated users must have one of the following:

1. The `imageUpdate` permission (assigned to the admin role).
2. The `imageUpdateOwn` permission (assigned to the author role) which will give the `imageUpdate` permission if the `isOwner` rule evaluates to true (which can only evaluate to true if we have the model so the owner can be checked).